# Pushing buffer into Stack in assembly and get it in C

Tags: c, assembly, x86, calling-convention

I'm making a project in C and Assembly and I need to get a string from assembly code in C so I used push to get it into stack and I can't have it in C.

This is my Assembly Code:

```
_continue:
     in al, dx
     test al, 8
     jz _continue

     mov cx, 512/2
     mov di, [buffer]
     mov dx, 1f0h
     rep insw
     push buffer
     ret
```

This is my C code:

```
extern STRING _readd();

void main()
{
     STRING recv = _readd();
     PrintString(recv);
     PrintChar('\n');
     PrintString("Done!");
     readStr();
}
```

Probably I'm not accessing to the stack at all in my C code is that the problem?

Comment: That won't work since you are overwriting the return address. You should probably just `mov ax, buffer` (assuming `STRING` is `char*` and you use near pointers).

Comment: What OS? What platform? What compiler? What calling convention?

Comment: C does not have a string type. And the language does not mandate a stack for local variables. Read about the idea of an ABI then study the one you have to use, then write your code accordingly. And I don't see whee you actually call one code from the other.

Comment: Yeah,,, 'push buffer, ret' is always going to end in tears.

Comment: I defined STRING as char*

If just push buffer and define that function with a parameter of type STRING, will it work?

Comment: Have you looked at the option of including the assembly *IN* your C program through the use of `asm` (assuming gcc or other compiler with this feature).

Comment: Yes, I'm using gcc and Ubuntu

Comment: This is 16 bit code with privileged instructions ... surely you don't intend to run it in linux natively, right? You use something like dosbox? Anyway, I have told you how to fix it.

Comment: I'll run it in VirtualBox. When I start it, it just crash.. Does nothing.. It should print the returned into recv and print done. Does nothing, even with mov ax, buffer

Comment: What do you run in virtualbox? Dos? How do you assemble and link? What format? `gcc` normally produces 32/64 bit code which is not compatible with your 16 bit asm.

Comment: Any good 16 bit c compiler?

Comment: I got "< ." and the "done!" with: "mov ax, [buffer] mov [esp+4], ax ret"

Comment: `mov ax, [buffer]` is wrong because that's a memory load, while you need the address and `mov [esp+4], ax` makes no sense whatsoever. *Well, depending on how your `buffer` is declared, of course. `mov di, [buffer]` should also probably be `mov di, buffer`.